# Outlook 2010 / 2016 - Disable Reply All Button via GPO

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-outlook, windows-registry, microsoft-outlook-2010, group-policy

I used Group Policy to disable the Reply to All button in Outlook 2010 and Outlook 2016. I did this by using the setting in the ADM/ADMX templates for the respective versions of Office to disable a Command bar ID.

When I use the Office 2016 admin templates and disable command bar ID 355 (Reply All), it disables the button as expected, however the same admin templates which is supposed to be compatible with 2010 based on documentation doesn't work as expected. The (Reply All) button was still active after setting to disable.

I then checked the Outlook 2010 Version and realised they were mostly 32bit versions, could this be the reason, is there a different approach to disabling these buttons.

I then decided to try to disable via Reg path cos someone had success with this approach and recommended it 
`Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\office\14.0\outlook\disabledcmdbaritemscheckboxes`

Name: TCID1,
Type: REG_SZ,
Value: 355

This key was non existent on the affected clients after thorough verification. Adding it also didn't disable the reply button.

Has anyone had success disabling a command bar ID for Outlook 2010 and specifically 32bit versions? If so, how did you do it?

Comment: I tested in my environment: Disable command bar ID 355 (Reply All) with Office 2010(32bit version) and found the “Reply All” button is disabled (grayed out). Please remember to wait a minutes and restart your Outlook. For your reference: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/8547759a-ef18-4e7b-a242-b89df87e8548/how-to-disable-the-quotreplyquot-not-quotreply-allquot-button-in-outlook-2010-with-gpo?forum=outlook

Comment: @Aidan 4. in the link you sent it shows on step 4 ---> **Click Show. In the Show Contents dialog box, enter 354 (the control ID for “Reply” button) in the Value field, and then click OK.** are we going with 354 or 355?

Comment: That thread is just a reference, 355 for Reply All; 354 for Reply. I want to show you that the command bar ID 355 also works in Offcie 2010 by that thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works as expected after following the steps @Aidan recommended which is on this link https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/8547759a-ef18-4e7b-a242-b89df87e8548/how-to-disable-the-reply-not-reply-all-button-in-outlook-2010-with-gpo?forum=outlook but funny enough i had to use the Reg variant for some win 7 systems in the same environment.